# why does gcc subtract 1 from an expression while assigning the expression?

Tags: c++, gcc

while solving a problem using code::blocks IDE and C++ , an expression like 
`result[i] += ((res*1.0 /10)-(res/10)) * 10;`, if the result of the right expression is 8 after the assignment to `result[i]` it becomes 7, so `result[i]` holds 7 instead of 8.

Here is the whole function:
it takes two numbers and convert each of them into an array. E.g. 34 becomes `{4,3}` , so I add numbers as arrays , not as normal numbers.

`void add(char a, char b)
    {
        //get # digits of both
        int n1=0;
        int n2=0;
        char temp1=a;
        char temp2=b;

        //counting # digits of first number
        while( (temp1*1.0/10) != 0 )
        {
            n1++;
            temp1/=10;
        }

        //counting # digits of second number
        while( (temp2*1.0/10) != 0 )
        {
            n2++;
            temp2/=10;
        }

        int maxi=max(n1,n2);
        int mini=min(n1,n2);

        //filling arr1 arr2
        char * arr1=new char[n1];
        char * arr2=new char[n2];
        char * result=new char[maxi+1];
        //fill result with zeros
        for(int k=0; k<maxi+1; k++)
            result[k]=0;

        temp1=a;
        for(int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        {
            arr1[i]=((temp1*1.0 /10)-(temp1/10)) * 10;
            temp1/=10;
        }

        temp2=b;
        for(int j=0; j<n2; j++)
        {
            arr2[j]=((temp2*1.0 /10)-(temp2/10)) * 10;
            temp2/=10;
        }


        //add both arrays
        char res=0;
        char overflow=0;

        for(int i=0; i<maxi; i++)
        {
            if(i<mini)
            {
                res=arr1[i]+arr2[i];
                if(checkDigit(res))
                {
                    result[i]=res;
                }
                else
                {

////////////////////////////
//>>>>>>>>            result[i] += ((res*1.0 /10)-(res/10)) * 10;
///////////////////////////
                    overflow=res/10;
                    result[i+1]=overflow;


                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(n1<n2)
                {
                    result[i]+=arr2[i];
                }
                else if(n2<n1)
                {
                    result[i]+=arr1[i];
                }

            }






        }

        if(!checkDigit(result[maxi-1]))
        {
            // assign overflow before
            result[maxi]=result[maxi-1]/10;
            result[maxi-1]=((result[maxi-1]*1.0 /10)-(result[maxi-1]/10)) * 10;

        }




        for(int i=0; i<maxi+1; i++)
            cout<<(int)result[i]<<endl;




    }`

Comment: Why not print out what is already in `result[i]` before the calculation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Galik `result[i]` contains Zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a floating point operation.  Floating point operations on computers are not particularly accurate.  Not for base10 anyway.  What is likely happening is that your result is something like 7.9999999999991.  The various text streams in the standard library will print this as 8, but it's not.  Then when you assign to `result[i]`, which is a char--an integral type--you get the standard "chop off everything after the ." response from the compiler.

The simple response to this is a round operation.  Add .5 to the result and then convert to an integral.  There are a variety of solutions to this problem though depending on the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You are using floating point math, which will introduce rounding errors, you also then convert them to integer which truncates (possibly what you want in your programm).

Rule of thumb: dont expect exact results with floating point math. The details would fill a course that take a semester or more.

For your program, you should get to know the remainder operation, I think it does exactly hwat you intend to do:

```
arr1[i]=temp1 %= 10;
temp1 / =10;
```

Comment: that's right , the floating point math was the problem . Thank you :)